# Perforce workspaces and multiple branches

Tags: intellij-idea, perforce

I'm trying to figure out the best way to setup Perforce workspaces when working with multiple branches for different parts of the code base.

Let's say that my default workspace mapping is as follows:

```
//depot/foo/trunk/... //my_client/trunk/foo/...
//depot/foo1/trunk/... //my_client/trunk/foo1/...
//depot/foo2/trunk/... //my_client/trunk/foo2/...
```

And I need to work with both `foo` and `foo1` together as `foo1` is dependent on `foo`.

Now, I want to create a new branch of `foo1` say `branch1` but I do not want to create a branch for `foo` and `foo2` but I need to work with `foo` and `foo2` trunk and `foo1` branch1 together. Due to the way the code is structured, for compilation purposes `foo1` and `foo2` needs to be in the same folder.

Should I create another workspace with the following mapping?

```
//depot/foo/trunk/... //my_client/trunk/foo/...
//depot/foo1/branch1/... //my_client/branch1/foo1/...
//depot/foo2/trunk/... //my_client/branch1/foo/...
```

And switch to this workspace when I want to work on the branch. Note that `foo` is still pointing to `//my_client/trunk/foo/`

My development IDE is Intellij, so I'll create 2 projects. First project that has 3 modules for `foo`, `foo1`, `foo2` in trunk. The second project will have the existing module `foo` for the trunk code, new modules for `foo1` in branch1 and `foo2` in trunk.

I first tried to map all of this in one perforce workspace but soon found out that I cannot map the same location in the depot to 2 separate local locations in the same workspace.

For the project `foo` for which I'm working on trunk and did not create a branch, I do not want to go through the whole project/Intellij module setup process and would like to reuse the existing local copy and setup.

Is this the right way to approach this or is there a better way to do this? I'm quite new to Perforce and still figuring out how it works. A similar scenario was quite easy to setup with Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your mapping looked like when you tried having it all in one workspace, but it sounds like you want:

```
//depot/foo/trunk/...    //my_client/trunk/foo/...
//depot/foo1/trunk/...   //my_client/trunk/foo1/...
//depot/foo1/branch1/... //my_client/branch1/foo1/...
```

which is a perfectly valid one-to-one mapping.  This on the other hand would not work:

```
//depot/foo/trunk/...    //my_client/trunk/foo/...
//depot/foo/trunk/...    //my_client/branch1/foo/...
//depot/foo1/trunk/...   //my_client/trunk/foo1/...
//depot/foo1/branch1/... //my_client/branch1/foo1/...
```

because one set of depot files is mapped to two locations -- but you said that you want "foo" to stay in its existing local location, so having two copies of it isn't necessary (or desired) -- correct?

If you did want two different copies of foo (with a duplicate copy under the "branch1" local directory) then I'd do it by having two client views:

```
//depot/foo/trunk/...    //my_trunk_client/trunk/foo/...
//depot/foo1/trunk/...   //my_trunk_client/trunk/foo1/...
```

and

```
//depot/foo/trunk/...    //my_branch1_client/branch1/foo/...
//depot/foo1/branch1/... //my_branch1_client/branch1/foo1/...
```

Note that in the "branch1" client, the "trunk" depot path is mapped to the "branch1" client path, which is presumably what you'd want (again, if you just the "trunk" branch in the "trunk" local folder, you can do that within a single workspace).

Comment: Your second example reflects what I had tried. After seeing your solution, I realized that I need `foo` to stay in its existing local location, a `foo2` trunk copied into `branch1` and `foo1` branch1 in `branch1`, so its a combination of the three. Does you example mean that I have two workspace roots `my_trunk_client` and `my_branch1_client` for the same workspace? For a perforce perspective, is it better to work with two workspaces or a single workspace for this example?

Comment: Reading your answer again, I think your solution of two client views means having two different workspaces with completely different workspace roots. I'm not sure if that would help my updated scenario. In my examples above, trunk & branch1 have the same parent folder locally.